# Warning of too much figures open, code don't work as i want

Tags: python, plot, 3d, runtime-error, figure

I'm stuck within a problem I try to eliminate since nearly 3h...
So this is my code:

```
import csv 
import matplotlib as mpl 
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import cm 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d 
import pandas as pd  
import os
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator

dirPath=r"C:\Users\sfs\Documents\Datas\OSA_entpackt"
result=[os.path.join(dirPath,f)
for f in os.listdir(dirPath)
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirPath,f))]
for file in result:

    data = np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=",", names=["xdata","ydata"], skip_header=1534, skip_footer=599)

    #fig = plt.figure()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection":"3d"})
    #ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    Y=np.arange(0, 484, 1)
    X=np.arange(980, 1180, 1)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
    Z = np.sin(R)
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

    plt.plot(data['xdata'], data['ydata'])
    plt.close(fig)
```

I want to plot a 3D graph from a lot of datas. But not only that the code isn't working, I get the error of too much figures open. Have you guys any idea how to fix this problem/code?

I've search for this error, but this solutions didn't worked for me :(

Thx a lot!

Comment: What error message are you getting from your code?

Comment: actual it takes too much time to debug, so I don't get an error message...Shame on my working laptop..